# How to create a parametric wood blade facade?

Tags: modeling

[image]
[image]

How to create this kind of warped facade? Need this for an architectural visualization, it is a facade composed of wood blades that form a parametric wavy surface.

Comment: It looks like you're getting some great responses. Don't forget to tick the one that best answers your question as The Answer (click the check mark left of the post, below the up/down arrows).

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247285/how-to-create-a-beveled-blades-that-follow-the-shape-of-a-2d-image

Answer (score 19):

A procedural approach would be to scale a cube into single plank and give it an array modifier.

[image: Array]

Next add a cube (or anything) and give it an Ocean modifier and a Solidify modifier. Ocean can be modified as you wish and even animated. Resolution doesn't need to be high but you can do as you wish.

[image: Ocean]

Give the original cube a Boolean modifier with difference from the ocean. Everything is still easily modified at this point.

[image: Result]

[image: Result2]

[image: Result3]

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day!!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your visualization!

Comment: Had something similar in mind... with shrinkwrap project instead of boolean diff.

Comment: BatFINGER please share your answer. It's quite interesting to see how other people approach the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a destructive and a non-destructive way.

**Destructive**:

- Create your shapes:

[image]

- Delete the edges on one direction:

[image]

[image]

- Extrude the remaining vertices horizontally:

[image]

- Then vertically:

[image]

**Non-destructive**:

- Create a vertex group:

[image]

- Give your object a *Mask* modifier with the group as *Vertex Group*:

[image]

- Give your object a *Solidify* modifier, *Mode > Complex, Thickness Mode > Fixed, Boundary > Flat*:

[image]

Comment: I like your first approach because it's the only one so far to keep the tops of the slats at right-angles to their sides, which they would be, if CNC cut?

Comment: thanks, actually I don't know, would they be?

Comment: i like it both anyway - no matter what! :D

Comment: thanks Chris, what's up?

Answer (score 6):

You can sculpt it.

Make a sequence of subdivided planes. Then sculpt on it.

[image]

Once happy with the shape, extrude it, add bevel, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use math functions (Z math surface) from *"add mesh, extra objects"* addon.

For instance:

[image]

As we know the steps used by the addon and the subdivisions given to it, we can tune a cutting grid that will always work using a boolean modifier: simply make it so no vertices of the math shape overlap a face of the cutter object.

For instance, if X steps of the shape are every 1cm, make the cuts to be [0.9 to 2.1], [2.9, 3.1] etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just use a boolean modifier with wood prank array:

Create a wood prank add array modifier

[image]

Make a cube and subdivide one face:

[image]

Add a displace modifier to the cube, using any texture you want:

[image]

Subtract(Difference) this cube from your wood pranks:

[image]

#### pros

- easy to figure out why
- easy to change wave in general using texture
- no extras vertices after applied

#### cons

- computation heavy during boolean process
- not easy to fine tune with curve

Comment: Thank you so much!