# How to create a beveled "blades" that follow the shape of a 2D image?

Tags: bevel, displacement

The picture below is from the opening animation of a Brazilian news program called "Bom Dia Brasil".

I really liked the beveled lines creating the country boundaries.

My interest is how that could be made by using a "dynamic" approach. I mean, imagine the country boundaries being replaced by a human face or other image, working like the "base shape".

With my current knownledge I can only think using displacement or maybe node geometry.

[image: tv show opening]

The full animation is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCVvHufdl6g&ab_channel=GuilhermeSantos

Comment: *"With my current knownledge I can only think using displacement[...]"* - and why it doesn't work?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I included the link for the full animation. I can't figure out if the displacement would be a good option because of the individual animation of each "line". It make sense?

Comment: Why do you say that it's bevel? I seems like displacement to me.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Yep. Technically, "displacement" seems more correct indeed. In a more generic domain, I was looking for an English term to describe it, as "bevel" or "groove".

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194599/how-to-create-a-parametric-wood-facade

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

1. Get a mesh object shaped like a world map. Maybe download an SVG
   world map from the internet, there are plenty around, import it and
   convert to a single mesh object.
2. Create a simple mesh plane oriented vertically.
3. Add just both top vertex to a new vertex group, leaving the bottom
   ones out.

[image]

4. Add two *Array* modifiers in X and Y axis so you end up with
   multiple long, paper thin strips, big enough to cover the world map,
   and dense enough to have the desired degree of detail.
5. Add a *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier to your mesh plane, point
   to the previously created vertex group and to the world map object
   as target.
6. Set geometry to *Face* and adjust the values of lowest and highest
   according to your mesh and scene scale. In this case, to achieve an
   elevated land mass you'll likely have to set a *Highest* value lower
   than the *Lowest*.

[image]

7. Add a *Displace* modifier to the plane, set it to either whichever
   local axis is pointing upwards, or global Z axis, depending on the
   orientation of your plane object.

[image]

Optionally add a *Solidify* modifier if you want to add some thickness to the blades, preceded by a *Bevel* modifier if you want smooth rounded corners for the height transitions in the blades.

Comment: Omg. Speechless.

Comment: This is a great example for the VeryexWeightProximity modifier!

Comment: thx! https://p4n.short.gy/SGJKzm